# How to include a static library and have its #import paths still be valid?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, compiler-errors

Say I have a static library that was created with the following file structure:

- Folder1

  - File1.h
- Folder2

  - File2.h

Now inside of `File1.h`, it refers to `File2.h` without a path (e.g. `#import File2.h`). The library builds successfully. (It doesn't require the full path (i.e. `#import Folder2/File2.h`) because both files are part of the same project.)

Now when I include this library in another project, that `#import File2.h` statement no longer compiles, and I have to change it to `#import Folder2/File2.h` (or something similar). This means that I have to modify the original library, which is not good.

The specific error message I get is:

> File2.h: No such file or directory

There doesn't seem to be a way to let it know that both files should be a part of this new project, since the only two files I see after I included the library are `MyLib.xcodeproj` and `lixMyLib.a`.

The way I included the static library in my new project is by doing the following:

1. Drag `MyLib.xcodeproj` into my new project.
2. Add the `libMyLib.a` file to my new project's target.
3. Add to the Header Search Paths a relative path to the home directory of my library (the folder that contains `Folder1` and `Folder2`).

Is there any way I can have it automatically know where to find these files just as it was able to do in the library itself? I realize that I can probably add the paths `Folder1` and `Folder2` to the Header Search Paths of my new project, but I'm looking for a better way, since these two folders are just an example, and it could just as easily be 50 folders I would need to include. I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require me to type the paths to all 50 of those folders, if possible.

Comment: I don't get it, why does someone wants to include a .m file?

Comment: @JustSid: Oops, that was just an example. I fixed it to use .h instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the "Recursive" checkbox next to the path to the parent folder of all those headers.