# Static Library import

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, import-libraries

I created a *static Library* but I am unable to import it. Here are the steps that i followed to add it to my project.

1) From finder, I dragged my library *.xcodeproj* into my main project.

2) I selected the main project, went to target and then build phases.

3) I added the library under Link Binary With Libraries and Target Dependencies.

4) Under Build Settings -- Header Search Paths, I added `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)`.

5) I also added `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags`.

However when I try importing the library, it's not being recognised.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: If you have copied the _.xcodeproj_ into your main project then you can simply mention `${SRCROOT}/<Path to the lib headers>/` under _Header Search Path_. Ensure there is no _space_ anywhere in the path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074871/how-to-include-a-static-library-and-have-its-import-paths-still-be-valid

Comment: @Amar I tried that too but the same issue still arises.

Comment: @iPatel This solution didn't work in my case.

Comment: @Amrita Can you post the error that you are getting?

Comment: @amrita - u have superb title of ur question just search on google, you may be find your solution, actually i have no idea in your case so i can not give you my own suggestion :)

Comment: #import "MyLibrary" -- 'MyLibrary' file not found. @Amar

Comment: @Amrita Are you sure you have copied entire _MyLibrary_ project in your main project?

Comment: @Amar Yes. Completely sure.

Comment: @Amrita Okay, then thats weird. Try making the _User Search Path_ as `${SRCROOT}` and recursive. Basic issue is that the path you are specifying is incorrect, hence the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can include library by two ways either u can drag and drop library.xcodeproj into your project or you can include .lib file into your project. It might be possible that your lib file was not build properly.
You could build ur lib file by opening ur library.xcodeproj in xcode select build target as iOS Device and build the project.
If build is successful u could find the newly created .lib file to the following path **LIbrary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData** now remove the previous lib file and include the new lib.