# Xcode import library header in subproject

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've complex app with many subprojects.

App Project Structure

[image: App Project Structure]

All projects (and sub project) are compiled as static library. Resulting app is an iOS app.

I would like to reference **Lumberjack** project in subproject **BackgroundGeolocation** with:

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

Above import works fine within sibling projects (like in **RCTBackGroundGeolocation**), but not in it's subproject **BackgroundGeolocation**.

I get error: **'CocoaLumberjack/Some CocoaLumberjack.h' cannot be found.**

If I set **"Header Search Paths"** for **BackgroundGeolocation** project to include **Lumberjack** project path then I can:

```
#import "CocoaLumberjack.h"
```

But I really want to use first variant as I'm using same project on more then project. Will be thankful for any advice.

Comment: You  need to give us more information. Is Project1 a framework or other type of dynamically loaded library? How is it packaged?

Comment: Ok. I've edited my question. Hopefully it's more understandable now.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `#import <Foo/Bar.h>` syntax for static libraries. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074871/how-to-include-a-static-library-and-have-its-import-paths-still-be-valid) shows how to make `#import  "Foo/Bar.h"` work.

Comment: It's working fine for sibling projects, but not for nested subprojects. Meaning if you have projects A,B,C->D. You can #import <A/A.h> from B,C, but not D (which is child of C). I can hack it with #ifdef macros and Header Search Paths, but looking for cleaner solution.